# How to save local storage cypress react

Tags: reactjs, testing, cypress

Hi sorry for my bad English.

I am making a test in my project using cypress. I have found this problem/issue after

```
it("call login",() => ...)
```

The cypress clears my local storage deleting my auth, causing the next request returning my auth as undefined as it was deleted in local storage

How to save the local storage after it calling the above login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "feature" of Cypress, to help prevent tests from affecting other tests by leaving data around. The idea is to make each test run in a 'fresh' environment, free from leftovers of anything else.

In your cypress code, within any `it()` block, cookies and local storage items are preserved, so one approach is to basically put everything in one (possibly large) `it()` block.

Another approach is to copy localstorage values into a variable, and then restore the values within each `it()` block. You can also do this in the `beforeEach` section.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-localstorage-commands) plugin for preserving `localStorage` between tests.

You could create a command for login with an specific user:

```js
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

Cypress.Commands.add('loginAs', (UserEmail, UserPwd) => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/login",
    body: {
      user: {
        email: UserEmail,
        password: UserPwd,
      }
    }
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      cy.setLocalStorage("accessToken", body.accessToken);
      cy.setLocalStorage("refreshToken", body.refreshToken);
    });
});
```

And then use that command for making login before all tests, and the [cypress-localstorage-commands plugin](https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-localstorage-commands) for preserving the `localStorage` between tests:

```js
describe("When user is authenticated", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.loginAs("foo@user.com", "foo-password");
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  it("should be logged in", () => ...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setItem` method

```
storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);
```

The `setItem()` method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name and value, will add that key to the given Storage object, or update that key's value if it already exists.

```
onSave() => {
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(state))
}
```